# 2D Array causes animation glitch (Processing)

Tags: processing

BRIEF:
For an assignment, I must create a Space Invaders game (using Processing) with my own theme. I have created a spaceship that moves left and right and also shoots. I have also created one enemy that moves all the way down. I now want to use a 2D Array (I must use a 2D Array, a spec in the assignment) to create a fleet of enemies. I want the fleet to be 3 rows with 5 enemies on each row.

PROBLEM:
When I ever I implement a 2D Array my self, the movement of the fleet stops after going down a little bit. When I don't use a 2D Array and just have one enemy, it goes down fine. So I want the awesome people of Stackoverflow to help me figure out why this is happening and how we can fix this. If you can successfully implement a 2D Array with the fleet going down just as it did with one enemy, then you have found exactly what I have been trying to do for a weeks now.

LINK:
I put up the code for the game I have so far. Note, that these codes will show the game with just one enemy, not the one with the fleet of enemies and the glitch.

Thank you guys and I hope you guys can help me learn and improve my skills.

*Note: My code is messy and the names I have used are I bad I know, I will fix all this before I submit.*

```
player hero1;

Cell fleet;

final int RED=1;

int testColour(color c) {
  if (c==color(255,0,0))
     return RED;
    return OTHER;
}

PFont font1;
PFont font2;

final int MENU=0;
final int START=1;
int gameMode = MENU;

float x = 0;
float y = 0;

float cX;
float cY;

boolean b1 = false;
boolean b2= false;

void setup()  {
    size(900, 600);
    hero1 = new player(x + 450, 550, 80, 40);
    fleet = new Cell(cX, cY, 20, 20); 
    font1 = loadFont("Font1.vlw");
    font2 = loadFont("Font2.vlw");
    bullets = new ArrayList();

    grid = new Cell[cols][rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      // Initialize each object
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i*(width-800),j*200,20,20); 
      }
      }
 }

void draw()  {

       if(gameMode==MENU) {
         screen1(); 
       }

       if(gameMode==START) {
         screen2(); 
};
  moveAll();//move all the bullets
  displayAll();
}

void keyPressed() {
if(key==' ' && gameMode==MENU) {
         gameMode=START;
       }
    if(keyCode == RIGHT && gameMode==START) {
      b1=true;
      b2=false;
}
if(keyCode == LEFT && gameMode==START) {
      b2=true;
      b1=false;
}
if(keyCode == ' ' && gameMode==START) {
  Bullet temp = new Bullet(hero1.x,hero1.y);
  bullets.add(temp);
}
}

void keyReleased() {
    if(keyCode == RIGHT && gameMode==START) {
      b1=false;
}
if(keyCode == LEFT && gameMode==START) {
      b2=false;
}
}
```

---

```
ArrayList <Bullet> bullets;

class Bullet
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  Bullet(float tx, float ty)
  {
    x = tx;
    y = ty;
  }
  void display()
  {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(x,y, 10, 10);
  }
  void move()
  {
    y -= 5;
  }
}
void moveAll()
{
  for(Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.move();
  }
}
void displayAll()
{
  for(Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.display();
  }
}
```

---

```
Cell[][] grid;

boolean b3=false;
boolean b4=true;
boolean b5=false;

int cols = 5;
int rows = 2;
color pixel;

class Cell {
  float cX,cY;   


  Cell(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH) {
    cX = tempX;
    cY = tempY;
  } 

  void display2() {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(cX+30,cY+100,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+95,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+90,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+85,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+85,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+90,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+95,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+100,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+105,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+110,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+110,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+105,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+130,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+135,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+135,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+130,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+125,5,5);



   if(b4==true) {  //moving right
      b3 = false;
      b5 = false;
      cX += 2;
    }
    else if(b5==true) { //moving left
      b3 = false;
      b4 = false;
      cX -= 2;
    }

   if( (b4 == true && cX >= 780) || (b5 == true && cX <= -1)) 
   {
      b3 = true;  //moving down
      b4 = false;
      b5 = false;
      //b4=false;
      //b5=false;
    }

   if( b3 == true) //moving down
   {
       cY += 3;
      if (cY % 10 == 0)  //moving down 10 pixels
      {
        b3=false;
        if ( cX >= 780)  //if it is on the right edge
        {
          b4 = false;
          b5 = true;
        }
        else if ( cX <= -1 ) //if it is on the left edge
        {
         b4 = true;
          b5 = false;
          cY += 3;
        }
      }
  }
  }

}
```

---

```
class player {
         float x = 0;
         float y = 0;
         float widthX;
         float widthY;
         float speedX = 3;

         player(float x, float y, float widthX, float widthY) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.widthX = widthX;
         this.widthY = widthY;
       }
    void hero() {
      stroke(0);
      fill(255);
         rect(x, y-30, 10, 10);
         rect(x-10, y-40, 10, 10);
         rect(x-20, y-30, 10, 10);
         rect(x-30, y-20, 10, 10);
         rect(x+10, y-20, 10, 10);
         rect(x-40, y-10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-20, y-10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-10, y-10, 10, 10);
         rect(x, y-10, 10, 10);
         rect(x+20, y-10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-40, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x-20, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x-10, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x+20, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x-60, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x+40, y, 10, 10);
         rect(x-60, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-50, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-40, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-30, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-10, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x+10, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x+20, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x+30, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x+40, y+10, 10, 10);
         rect(x-40, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x-30, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x-20, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x-10, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x+10, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x+20, y+20, 10, 10);
         rect(x+20, y+30, 10, 10);
         rect(x, y+30, 10, 10);
         rect(x-20, y+30, 10, 10);
         rect(x-40, y+30, 10, 10);


if(b1==true) {
  x+=4;
}
if(b1==false) {
   x=x;
}
     if(b2==true) {
   x-=4;
 }
if(b2==false) {
   x=x;
}
     } 
   void right() {
   }
 }
```

---

```
    void screen1() {  
         PImage img;
         img = loadImage("Pictures/MenuScrn.jpg");
         image(img, 0, 0);
         textFont(font1, 50);
         fill(203, 208, 55);
         text("Space Mushrooms", 70, 100);
         textFont(font2, 40);
         fill(255);
         text("Press SpaceBar to start", 90, 300);
       }
 void screen2() {
         background(0);
         hero1.hero();
         fleet.display2();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code to ask us to debug for you. You should try posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead. For example, your problem has nothing to do with the player movement, the bullets, the game modes, or the fonts, so you might as well just take them out.

Here's what an MCVE for your problem might look like:

```
Cell[][] grid;

boolean movingDown=false;
boolean movingRight=true;
boolean movingLeft=false;

void setup() {
  size(900, 600);

  int cols = 5;
  int rows = 2;
  grid = new Cell[cols][rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      // Initialize each object
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i*(width-800), j*200, 20, 20);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
      grid[i][j].display2();
    }
  }
}

class Cell {
  float cX, cY;   

  Cell(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH) {
    cX = tempX;
    cY = tempY;
  } 

  void display2() {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(cX+30, cY+100, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+35, cY+95, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+35, cY+90, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+40, cY+85, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+45, cY+80, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+50, cY+80, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+55, cY+75, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+60, cY+75, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+65, cY+75, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+70, cY+75, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+75, cY+80, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+80, cY+80, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+85, cY+85, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+90, cY+90, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+90, cY+95, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+95, cY+100, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+95, cY+105, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+95, cY+110, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+95, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+90, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+85, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+80, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+75, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+70, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+70, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+70, cY+125, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+65, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+60, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+55, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+55, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+55, cY+125, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+50, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+45, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+45, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+40, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+35, cY+120, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+30, cY+115, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+30, cY+110, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+30, cY+105, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+40, cY+125, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+40, cY+130, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+45, cY+135, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+50, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+55, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+60, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+65, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+70, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+75, cY+140, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+80, cY+135, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+85, cY+130, 5, 5);
    rect(cX+85, cY+125, 5, 5);

    if (movingRight) {  //moving right
      movingDown = false;
      movingLeft = false;
      cX += 2;
    } else if (movingLeft) { //moving left
      movingDown = false;
      movingRight = false;
      cX -= 2;
    }

    if ( (movingRight && cX >= 780) || (movingLeft == true && cX <= -1)) 
    {
      movingDown = true;  //moving down
      movingRight = false;
      movingLeft = false;
    }

    if (movingDown) //moving down
    {
      cY += 3;
      if (cY % 10 == 0)  //moving down 10 pixels
      {
        movingDown=false;
        if ( cX >= 780)  //if it is on the right edge
        {
          movingRight = false;
          movingLeft = true;
        } else if ( cX <= -1 ) //if it is on the left edge
        {
          movingRight = true;
          movingLeft = false;
          cY += 3;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your problem is caused because you're deciding which direction to move **the whole fleet** based off of **every single member** of that fleet. That's not quite right- you don't move down when the middle member is at the edge of the screen, you move down when the **left-most** or **right-most** member is at the edge of the screen.

Your logic is iterating through every member, saying "this member is not at the edge of the screen, better move right. Now this member is at the edge of the screen, better move down. But this member was already moving down, so we're done moving down". All of this contradiction confuses your logic, and you end up constantly moving left and right, down and stopping... so you end up not moving at all.

**You need to refactor your logic so you only base your movements off of the members of the fleet that matter.**

Try stepping through your code with a debugger, or just with a piece of paper and a pencil, until you understand exactly what's going on in the code. That's one of the most important skills you need to learn as a programmer.

This is homework designed to teach you about 2D arrays, so doing that for you would be academic dishonesty. If you have a smaller example you want help with instead of your full homework project, we'll be happy to help with that. Good luck.

Comment: How can I specifically control a single object within the 2D-Array? I know how to move the entire fleet but how can I specify the top-left enemy within the fleet for example?